# Search method not working as intended

Tags: java

I am building bookstore system and one of the method I have is `search` which will search for the book based on the book's ID code.
The problem is that the code doesn't work if the user added more than two books. If the user added 2 books, and searched for the second book in the array, the method would print the ID code of the second book but the info of the first book.

Here is the code of the `search` method

```
public void searchBook(){
    boolean invalidInput;
    int q = -1;

    do {        
        try {        
            invalidInput = false;
    System.out.println("Enter the book's code you want to search for : ");
        q = s.nextInt();
        for (int i = 0; i<=items.length; i++){
            if(q == items[i].getCode(z)){
                System.out.println(items[i]);
                break;
            }else{
                System.out.println("The book is not found");
            }
        }

        } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
    System.out.println("Please enter a valid code [Numbers Only]");
            s.next();
    invalidInput = true;  // This is what will get the program to loop back
        }
    } while (invalidInput);

}
```

this is the Items class

```
public class Items {
private int code, quantity;
private String description;
private double costPrice, sellingPrice;
String status, discount;

public Items(){
    this.code = 1111;
    this.quantity = 1;
    this.description = "Action";
    this.costPrice = 12.00;
    this.sellingPrice = 16.00;
    this.discount = "5%";
    this.status = "Unvailable";

}

public Items(int code, String description, int quantity,
        double costPrice, double sellingPrice, String status, String discount){
    this.code = code;
    this.description = description;
    this.quantity = quantity;
    this.costPrice = costPrice;
    this.sellingPrice = sellingPrice;
    this.status = status;
    this.discount = discount;
}

public void setCode(int code){
    this.code = code;
}

public void setQuantity(int quantity){
    this.quantity = quantity;
}

public void setDescription(String description){
    this.description = description;
}

public void setcostPrice(double costPrice){
    this.costPrice = costPrice;
}

public void setsellingPrice(double sellingPrice){
    this.sellingPrice = sellingPrice;
}

public void setStatus(String status){
    this.status = status;
}

public void setDiscount(String discount){
    this.discount = discount;
}

public int getCode(int code){
    this.code = code;
    return this.code;
}

public int getQuantity(int quantity){
    this.quantity = quantity;
    return this.quantity;
}

public String getDescription(String description){
    this.description = description;
    return this.description;
}

public double getcostPrice(double costPrice){
    this.costPrice = costPrice;
    return this.costPrice;
}

public double getsellingPrice(double sellingPrice){
    this.sellingPrice = sellingPrice;
    return this.sellingPrice;
}

public String getStatus(String status){
    this.status = status;
    return this.status;
}

public String getDiscount(String discount){
    this.discount = discount;
    return this.discount;
}

public String toString(){
    return ("code : " + this.code + "\nQuantity : " + this.quantity +
            "\nDescription : " + this.description + "\nCost price : " + this.costPrice
            + "\nSelling price : " + this.sellingPrice + "\nstatus : " + this.status
            + "\ndiscount : " + this.discount);
}
```

}

the Initialaized items
             public class userChoices {

```
   Items[] items = new Items[200];
AddItem add = new AddItem();
Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
int z,x;
double c,v;
String n,m,b;
```

Comment: could you show us how you initialize `items` ?

Comment: Not sure if it's the only problem, but you should change `i<=items.length` to `i<items.length`

Comment: As @yunandtidus said, the `items` class's code would be helpful. I personally would only be interested in the toString method, could you post that?

Comment: 1. You made a custom constructor fro your item. That's nice, but if you already did it, use it too. Like this: `Item newItem = new Item(/*parameters*/);`  

2. It's not a really good idea to put objects into an array. Rather, use an `ArrayList<Items>`

Comment: Is it possible to see the code where new Books are added to items?

Comment: Why do your getters have a parameter? I don't see a way to retieve anything having been previously set for your Items class.

Comment: thanks Philippe i solved it thanks to ur question, i didn't notice that mistake -_-

Answer (score 0):

i solved the problem thanks to Philippe who replayed as a comment
by removing the parameters in my getters :)

Answer (score 0):

Why not just create a Map of Integer and Item? You could then easily get the item from the code.

Example:

```
Map<Integer, Item> map = new HashMap<>();

map.put(1, new Item(1));
map.put(2, new Item(2));

Item item1 = map.get(1);
Item item2 = map.get(2);
```

Simplified `Item` class to demonstrate implementation.

```
  public static class Item {
    final int code;

    public int getCode() {
      return code;
    }

    public Item(int code) {
      this.code = code;
    }
  }
```